# Bulk delete using backbone

Tags: backbone.js

I have a view which contains list of employees, end user select the employees and delete the employees more than one at ones.

Each row of the list contains a check box. End user select multiple check boxes and press delete button. The selected records need to delete.

MVC controller takes care of the delete part. Signature of the delete method is:

```
DeleteEmployes(List<int> empIds).
```

How can I achieve this?

My backbone model is:

```
var emp = Backbone.Model.extend({
defaults:{
             Id:null,
             fname:null,
             lname:nulll.
}
});
```

Comment: Does your backend support multiple deleting of models? ‌Backbone doesn't support bulk deleting, you can achive this (if your backend support that) by just one ajax call!

Answer (score 1):

In order to delete all models with one request, you need to extend backbone's collection with a method that sends a HTTP DELETE request to a controller action that uses the 'DeleteEmployes(List empIds)' function. Something like this may do the trick.

```
Backbone.Collection.prototype.bulk_destroy = function() {
  var modelId = function(model) { return model.id };
  var ids = this.models.map(modelId);
  // Send ajax request (jQuery, xhr, etc) with the ids attached
  // Empty the collection after the request
  // You may want to include this as a success callback to the ajax request
  this.reset(); 
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a Backbone Collection and loop through it, destroying each model. This will send the DELETE command for each model to the server.

```
var Employees = new Backbone.Collection([
 { name: 'Employee1' }, 
 { name: 'Employee2' }, 
 { name: 'Employee3' }, 
]);

Employees.each(function(model){
  model.destroy();
});
```

Comment: To my knowledge, there is no `destroy` method for a `Backbone.Collection`.

Comment: My bad. I fixed that.